# How to make your own GTK Theme?

Tags: themes, gtk

I am looking to make my own GTK Theme, but I can't find any tutorials that seem to relate to what I want. They're all about installing one etc. But I want to design my own.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

[GTK Theming Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes)

[GTK Theming Guide](https://gtkthemingguide.surajmandal.in)